# Why are the congruences $p^2-1 \equiv 0(\mod 8)$ and $p^e \equiv 1 + e(p-1) (\mod 4)$ for odd prime $p$ and $e \ge 1$ true?

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Why are  the congruences $p^2-1 \equiv 0(\mod 8)$ and $p^e \equiv 1 + e(p-1) (\mod 4)$ for odd prime $p$ and $e \ge 1$ true ?

Suppose $p$ is an odd prime.

I see easily that $p-1 \equiv 0 (\mod 2)$.

However why is $p^2-1 \equiv 0(\mod 8)$ neccesarily true ?

Also why does the congruence hold: $p^e \equiv 1 + e(p-1) (\mod 4)$ for $e \ge 1$ ?

```
I see we can write $p = 1 + (p-1)$ and then use binomial expansion ?
```

Comment: Your idea for the last question is correct. The point is that higher powers $(p-1)^k$, $k\ge2$, will be divisible by all factors of $p-1$ raised to $k$. I suspect that lab bhattacharjee or somebody else who wants to give you a copy/pastable solution will do so in a minute or so...

Answer (score 1):

For odd integer $\displaystyle p=2r+1, p^2=(2r+1)^2=8\frac{r(r+1)}2+1\equiv1\pmod8$

$\displaystyle\implies p^{2r}\equiv1\pmod8, p^{2r+1}\equiv p$

and for $\displaystyle e=2s; 1+e(p-1)=1+2s(p-1)\equiv1\pmod4$ as $p-1$ is even

Similarly for odd $\displaystyle e=2s+1; 1+e(p-1)= 1+(2s+1)(p-1)=2s(p-1)+p\equiv p\pmod 4$ as $p-1$ is even

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, an easier way (for me at least) to see it is as follow:

$(p-1),p,(p+1)$ are consecutive natural numbers. Since $p$ is odd, both of the others are even. Also, since every alternate even number is a multiple of 4, exactly one of them is a multiple of 4. Therefore the product $(p-1)(p+1)$ is divisible by $4 \times 2$, i.e. $8 \mid (p^2 - 1)$.

For the second, use Binomial Theorem, as others have suggested. It's a quick and easy proof.